# Show product variations on the product category and shop pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to display product variations for some (not all) variable products on the shop and product-category pages based on a custom field I'm planning to add to each variable product. To keep pagination working, I can hook in to the `woocommerce_product_query` hook in WC_Query::product_query($q) but I can't figure out how to modify the query to give me what I'm after.

The logic I want to apply is:

```
//Pseudo-code
$loop = $query->get_all_products // i.e. not just for one page
foreach ( $loop as $product) {
    if ($product->is_simple) {
        display_simple($product)
    } else {
        $variations = wc_get_products($product->get_children());
        foreach ($variations as $product) {
            if ($product->custom_show_on_archive_pages) {
                display_variation($product)
            }            
        }
    }    
}
```

The problem with the above (apart from being pseudo-code) is that it assumes we have an array called `$loop` but actually we have a query object.

My ideal would be to modify the query so that it generates the results as per the pseudo-code, and then my archive-product.php template can use an if/else to display simple vs variable products.

Something like this in my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'show_variable_products');

function show_variable_products( $q ) {

    $meta_query = $q->get('meta_query');

    // Do something

    $q->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
}
```

I'm wondering if I need to actually run multiple queries somehow:

1. The original query but filtered to parent products
2. The children of these parent products (i.e. the variations), filtered to those with custom field checked
3. The original query but filtered to simple products
4. Merge (2) and (3)

Would this be possible?

Alternatively, is there another solution (that does not involve buying a plugin)?